# How to replace a single row in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to replace a row of a NumPy array by the same row after modification by a function.

Here is my code:

```
def _softmax(z):
   array = np.exp(z)
   array = np.divide(array,np.sum(array))
   return array

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,15,4,7]])
n =_softmax(a[0])
print(n)

a[0]= n
print(a[0])
```

I get the folowing result :

```
[0.0320586  0.08714432 0.23688282 0.64391426]
[0 0 0 0]
```

As you can see, `n` is okay, but `a[0]` won't change, except to `[0,0,0,0]`. 
 However, if I try:

```
a[0] = np.array([4,3,2,1])
```

...it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is because `a` is originally of type `np.int64`, whereas the output of your softmax is `np.float`.  You must change the precision of your NumPy array `a` to `np.float` or the assignment into the first row of `a` gets down-converted to integer precision:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,15,4,7]], dtype=np.float)
```

The reason why it is created with type `np.int64` originally is because all of your values are integer.  As soon as you change one of them to float, the array gets promoted to floating-point:

```
In [9]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,15,4,7]])

In [10]: a.dtype
Out[10]: dtype('int64')

In [11]: a = np.array([[1.0,2,3,4],[5,15,4,7]])

In [12]: a.dtype
Out[12]: dtype('float64')
```

Take note that I changed the precision for the value `1` to `1.0`.  You can do it this way if you like without explicitly specifying the type.  NumPy figures out what is contained in your array construction and infers the best type that matches all of the information provided.

Finally once we run through everything we get:

```
In [14]: a
Out[14]:
array([[ 0.0320586 ,  0.08714432,  0.23688282,  0.64391426],
       [ 5.        , 15.        ,  4.        ,  7.        ]])
```